# Using FsShell.run() to get remote hdfs file throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I need to implement a quick and simple hdfs get functionality in java code that works much like the command line "hadoop fs get", in that it supports wildcards.

Using the `Filesystem.copyToLocalFile()` method does not seem to offer this, but running `FsShell.run()` with the appropriate parameters seems to call the exact command line functionality, but for some reason it throws a null pointer exception when doing a get.

My code is the following:

```
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
        conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());

        FileSystem.setDefaultUri(conf, "hdfs://192.168.61.129:8020");

        FsShell hdfsShell = new FsShell(conf);


        String src = "/user/andrei-test/test.txt";
        String dst = "D:/temp/";

        hdfsShell.run(new String[]{ "-get", src, dst });
```

I also noticed that when doing a put:

```
hdfsShell.run(new String[]{ "-put", "D:/temp/test.txt", "/user/andrei-test/test-put.txt" });
```

Everything works normally.

Going into debug mode, i notice the exception is thrown from the java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start() method:

```
for (String arg : cmdarray)
        if (arg == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
```

When the cmd array has the following values:

```
[null, chmod, 0644, D:\temp\test.txt._COPYING_]
```

From here i'm a bit stumped, has anyone come across this issue before ? I also couldn't find an example of doing a get using FsShell.run() on google which i found a bit strange.

Comment: your cmdarray dump has `chmod` but the code you are posting above has `get` in the call to hdfsShell.  are you sure you've got it right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's right, again, the version with put and, as i've tried in the mean time, with rm work just fine. I'm assuming D:\temp\test.txt._COPYING_ is an intermediary file created to reflect operation status or something similar.

Comment: As a small update, i've checked this on separate hadoop clusters, a development cluster we're using here as well as a hortonworks vm i'm running locally. The dependencies i'm working with are hadoop-common and hadoop-hdfs, i've tried using different versions of these too. In all of these cases i'm getting the same results.

Comment: if you post the stack trace it might help

Comment: Sorry, yes, i guess i could have started with a stack trace. http://pastebin.com/K0796e9F

Answer (score 0):

Apparently doing a get this way does not work standalone as doing the get via `FileSystem.copyToLocalFile()`

What eventually fixed it was creating an environment variable `HADOOP_HOME` and ensuring `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe` was present